# On selecting Radio button then desire checkbox should be select

Tags: jquery

I want to make jQuery validation on radio button but I am unable to make working code .

I made this code but by this only one radio button is working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radio1').change(function() {
    $("#lhr1").prop("checked", true)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2 align="center"><b><i>Form Validation Assignment</i></b></h2>
      <form id="vald" class="form-horizontal" action="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="radio1">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Gender</label>
                <div class="container">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="male">Male
                              </label>
                              <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="female">Female
                              </label>
                      </div>
        </div>
    
        <input type="checkbox" name="lhr" value="lhr" id="lhr1"> You can go Lahore<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mtn" value="mtn" id="mtn1">You can go Multan<br>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="add">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

If i select Male (radio button) then checkbox (" You can go Multan") should be select and if I select Female (radio button) then (" You can go Lahore") should be select.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Also note that since both radio buttons have the same `name` value, checking one means unchecking the other, so one click causes both radio button to trigger a `change` event.

Comment: Yes because in one time only one should be select only.

Comment: *so one click causes both radio button to trigger a change event* Read again. That was the whole point of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be easier to use `data` attribute for male and female inputs like this ..

`<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="female" data-check-id="mtn1">`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="optradio"]').change(function() {
    $('#lhr1 , #mtn1').prop('checked' , false);
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-check-id')).prop('checked' , true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2 align="center"><b><i>Form Validation Assignment</i></b></h2>
      <form id="vald" class="form-horizontal" action="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="radio1">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Gender</label>
                <div class="container">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="male" data-check-id="lhr1">Male
                              </label>
                              <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="female" data-check-id="mtn1">Female
                              </label>
                      </div>
        </div>
    
        <input type="checkbox" name="lhr" value="lhr" id="lhr1"> You can go Lahore<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mtn" value="mtn" id="mtn1">You can go Multan<br>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="add">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#male').click(function(){        
        $('#mtn1').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#female').click(function(){      
        $('#lhr1').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To just (slightly) modify your code, this should also work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radio1').change(function() {
    // Get the currently selected gender
    let gender = $("input[name=optradio]:checked").attr("id");

    // Check checkboxes based on gender
    $("#lhr1").prop("checked", gender === "male")
    $("#mtn1").prop("checked", gender === "female")

  });
});
```